# I want to show notification even if my Android app is running

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, push-notification, notifications, amazon-sns

I am using AWS SNS to send push notification to both SNS topics and Device Endpoints. It shows notification if the app is not running but does not show notification while the app is running.

I will like to show notification even if the app is running because the notification will inform the app user of changes happening in another section of the app so they can go check it out when they are ready. Something like getting notification of a new Whatsapp message from another group chat while you are typing message to another person.

Below is the notification builder code. Any hint will be really appreciated. Thanks.

```
    private void displayNotification(final String message) {

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestID, notificationIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Bitmap large_icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
            R.mipmap.myImage);

    // Display a notification with an icon, message as content, and default sound. It also
    // opens the app when the notification is clicked.

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setLargeIcon(large_icon)
            .setContentTitle("My Subject Title")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(
            Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
}
```

Comment: Hi , this method called when the user clicked on the notification from the notification center in your app ?

Comment: It displays a notification with an icon, message as content, and default sound. It also opens the app when the notification is clicked.

Comment: So i think that in order to have in-app notification the best is to use BroadcastReceiver then you can subscribe to incoming notifications and handle them while the app is running.. you can follow this guide: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-broadcast-receiver-notification-tutorial/

Comment: Ok, thanks Ran Hassid for taking the time to respond.  Appreciate it. Looking into it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use this below code to show notification message.

```
 private static void generateNotification(Context context, final String message) 
 {
    try {
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
      //Define sound URI
          Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
          Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, DemoActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("message", message);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, RandomNumberGenerator.getRandom(),notificationIntent
                /*new Intent(context, LuncherActivity.class)*/, 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_small);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle("YOUR-APP-NAME");
      //  mBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
       // mBuilder.bigText(msg);
        mBuilder.setContentText(message);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mBuilder.setSound(soundUri);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        }

  }
```

> 

Create a random number genetor class like below

public class RandomNumberGenerator {

```
 public static int getRandom()
 {
    int random_number=0;    
     Random random = new Random();
     random_number= random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;
    return random_number;
   }

 }
```

Try it and let me know.its working in my case.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Appreciate your time and response.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(final String from, final Bundle data) {
    String message = getMessage(data);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "From: " + from);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Message: " + message);
    // Display a notification in the notification center if the app is in the background.
    // Otherwise, send a local broadcast to the app and let the app handle it.
    displayNotification(message);

  /*  if (isForeground(this)) {
        // broadcast notification
        broadcast(from, data);
    } else {
        displayNotification(message);
    } */
}
```

my displayNotification() function was not called because of the "if" conditional statement that will only display notification if the application is not in foreground. So now when onMessageReceived() gets the message it passes it directly to displayNotification() even if my application is currently running, which is what I want.